# CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")

Tags: python, mysql, flask, database-connection

I am new to the Python Flask and networking.
I built a web application using Python Flask and MySQL database.
It was deployed in a server instance and I am accessing it by using the server IP address. 
Sometimes it gives following exception.

```
CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server 
during query')
```

I want to run this application continuously.

Comment: Please remove SQL-Server tag from your question.

Comment: have you resolved this error?

Comment: I think , I did not close the SQL connection, that's why that error occurred. When I close the connection, it worked properly.